# Read More link to paragraph is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a readmore link at the end of each paragraph if its contents reach to the maximum character length.

This is my HTML -

```
<div class="row-two">
    <h5>Whitney Houston's daughter found</h5>
    <h6>Whitney Houston's daughter found unresponsive in bath</h6>
    <p class="more-from-expert">Bobbi Kristina Brown, the only daughter of the late pop star Whitney Houston and singer Bobby Brown, was found unresponsive in a bathtub at her Georgia home, but she was revived and rushed to a hospital, police say. Kristina Brown, the only daughter of the late pop star Whitney Houston and singer Bobby Brown, was found unresponsive in a bathtub.</p>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery -

```
// Expand and Collapse experts' profile information. 
var countChar = 200;
var ellipses = "...";
var moreLink = "Read More";
var lessLink = "Read Less";
$('.more-from-expert').each(function() {
  var htmlContent = $(this).html();
  var textContent = $(this).text();

  if (textContent.length > countChar) {

    var shortPara = textContent.substr(0, countChar);

    var paragraph = '<span class="container"><span>' + shortPara + '</span>' + '<span>' + ellipses + '</span></span><span class="allContent">' + htmlContent + '</span>';

    $(this).html(paragraph);
  $(this).after('<a href="" class="readmore">' + moreLink + '</a>');
  }

});

$(".readmore").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
    $(this).removeClass("less");
    $(this).html(moreLink);
  $(this).parent().prev().children('.allContent').fadeToggle(200, function(){
    $(this).prev().fadeToggle(200);
  });

  } else {
    $(this).addClass("less");
    $(this).html(lessLink);

  $(this).parent().prev().children('.container').fadeToggle(200, function(){
    $(this).next().fadeToggle(200);
  });
  }

  return false;

});
```

This coding display read more link properly. But paragraph contents not working accordingly.

This is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bacigogeyi/1/edit?html,js,output) with current code.

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this? 
Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have this

```
$(this).parent().prev().children...
```

Change it to this

```
$(this).prev().children...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the readmore function change the line

```
$(this).parent().prev().children()
```

to the

```
$(this).prev().children
```